# How to get the symbol diophantus minus symbol

Tags: diophantus

I need the diophantus minus symbol ([https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~cherlin/History/Papers2000/kirschm.html](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Echerlin/History/Papers2000/kirschm.html))

[image]

Comment: It is the letter Psi  inverted and truncated from the Greek alphabet  you can get the unicode value from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psi_(Greek) and rotate it

Comment: @Sebastiano It doesn't seem fair to say "look through this 400 page pdf".  Are you able to narrow that down a bit?

Comment: @Teepeemm I have given an input. I was just leaving.

Comment: @Teepeemm I have checked but there is nothing like that.

Comment: @Sebastiano I too checked, but failed to find

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't find the symbol, you could always draw it in TikZ:

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\DeclareMathOperator{\foo}{\tikz[
  baseline={(0,0.02ex)},
  line width=0.13ex,
  looseness=1.5,
  line cap=round
]{
  \draw (0,0) -- (0,1.1ex);
  \draw (-0.8ex,0.9ex) to[out=-60,in=180,in looseness=0.6] (0,1.1ex) to[out=0,in=-120,out looseness=0.6] (0.8ex,0.9ex);
}}

\begin{document}
$
  a \foo b
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is a good solution, but preferable to be a normal letter  rather than an operator. In that period maths were written like Add this to that and subtract from the total etc, with very little symbolism, other than numbers in Greek letters or similar. Cajori's book on the History of maths is an excellent resource and available on archive.org or libgen.

Comment: Still I could not find the symbol, I'm proceeding with your suggestion, thanks a lot